# worklight multi thread/servletcontext calling adapter

Tags: java, multithreading, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I've been having some problems with worklight and multi threading.

We have a batch importer that needs to run once everyday.
What we have done so far

- Importer is a servletContextListener
- Use Quartz to run importer as a cronjob

Everything in the code works fine except for calling the HTTP Adapters. Everytime a adapter is called a error message  "BaseProjectLocal is null" is retured.
The code does work fine if it is started by another worklight adapter.

It seems the error is there because he does not know how to access the adapters (i assume)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: BaseProjectLocal is null
at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.get(BaseProjectLocal.java:41)
at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal.get(ProjectLocal.java:55)
at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal.getWorklightBundlesS(ProjectLocal.java:113)
at com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightBundles.getInstance(WorklightBundles.java:28)
at com.ibm.nl.wwdw.server.util.AdapterCaller.doCall(AdapterCaller.java:25)
at com.ibm.nl.wwdw.server.connections.CommunityCollector.getMembersFromCommunity(CommunityCollector.java:50)
at com.ibm.nl.wwdw.server.importer.ConnectionsImporter.StartImport(ConnectionsImporter.java:53)
at com.ibm.nl.wwdw.server.importer.MyJob.execute(MyJob.java:17)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

2-jun-2014 17:38:56 com.ibm.nl.wwdw.server.importer.ConnectionsImporter StartImport
SEVERE: BaseProjectLocal is null

Java code calling the adapter

```
public static JSONObject doCall(String adapter, String path, String paramArray) {
    Logging.logger.warning(adapter+"/"+path+"?"+paramArray);
    DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();//This line gives the error report
    ProcedureQName procedureQName = new ProcedureQName(adapter, path);
    InvocationResult result = service.invokeProcedure(procedureQName, paramArray);
    Logging.logger.warning(result.toJSON().toString());
    return result.toJSON();
}
```

}

Comment: Is your `servletContextListener` configured with the same web project as Worklight? If not you might want to try that.
Also make sure you did not remove Worklight's own listener from `web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the thread has no authentication context. While it is possible to create an authentication context manually it is tricky to accomplish as it requires using internal APIs (meaning it is a path that is not supported, ...).

Something like this:

```
authService = (AuthenticationServiceBean);
getBeanFactory().getBean(AuthenticationService.BEAN_ID);
authContext = authService.createAuthenticationContext(realm, username, password);
AuthenticationContext.setThreadContext(authContext);
```

It is suggested to run the importer *outside* of Worklight, and invoke the adapter remotely (via HTTP).

Note however that the adapter should not be protected by other realms.